# Perl Catalyst Controller chains

Tags: perl, endpoint, chaining, catalyst

I am having trouble creating a 'flexible' endpoints. Is something along these lines possible:

```
# 1) List all Microarrays for this species
/regulatory/species/:species/microarray
sub microarray_list: Chained('species') PathPart('microarray') ActionClass('REST') { }

# 2) Information about a specific array
/regulatory/species/:species/microarray/:microarray
sub microarray_single: Chained('species') PathPart('microarray') CaptureArgs(1) ActionClass('REST') { }

# 3) Information about a probe on the array
/regulatory/species/:species/microarray/:microarray/probe/:probe
sub microarray_probe: Chained('microarray_single') PathPart('probe') Args(1) ActionClass('REST')
```

At startup 1) is not registered:

```
| /regulatory/species/*/id/*          | /regulatory/species (1)              |
|                                     | => /regulatory/id (1)                |
| /regulatory/species/*/microarray    | /regulatory/species (1)              |
|                                     | => /regulatory/microarray_list (...) |
| /regulatory/species/*/microarray/*- | /regulatory/species (1)              |
| /probe/*                            |
```

Any help should be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is `/regulatory/species/*/id/*` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, your problem is just that you don't have an *endpoint* for microarray_single. You probably want

```
sub microarray_list :Chained('species') PathPart('microarray')
                     ActionClass('REST') { }

# this is the chain midpoint, it can load the microarray for the endpoints to use
sub microarray :Chained('species') PathPart('microarray')
                CaptureArgs(1) { }

# this is an endpoint with the same path as the midpoint it chains off of
sub microarray_single :Chained('microarray') PathPart('')
                       Args(0) ActionClass('REST') { }

# and this is an endpoint that adds .../probe/*
sub microarray_probe :Chained('microarray') PathPart('probe')
                      Args(1) ActionClass('REST') { }
```

if there are other things that can come after `.../microarray/*/probe/*` then you would do likewise, changing `microarray_probe` from `Args(1) ActionClass('REST')` (endpoint) to `CaptureArgs(1)`, and then adding an endpoint with `:Chained('microarray_probe') PathPart('') Args(0) ActionClass('REST')` to handle the case where there are no additional path parts.

The important thing to keep in mind is that only chain *endpoints* (i.e. actions without `CaptureArgs`) correspond to valid URL paths.